# how to configure wampserver for getting connected to mssql server using PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL DB server using PDO. I have downloaded some .dll files from Microsoft's web page and copied them to wampserver's **wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext** folder. Then I edited php.ini which is located at **wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin** folder.

I added the following lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
;extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

I have shutdown wampserver and run it again. I can see those four extensions on the menu **PHP -> PHP Extensions**, when I click on wampserver's tray icon.

Then I have tried to create a connection using the code below:

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=1.2.3.4,1433;Database=database.mdf', 
                'user', 'password', 
                array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
               );
```

When I call the page from browser I get

> could not find driver

error.

First, How can I connect to mssql server with PDO?
Second, Is there any point I missed about insatallation and/or configuration?

#### EDIT

Below, you can see my php.ini file's extensions section.

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_shmop.dll
; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
;extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

**EDIT 2:**

Finally I have discovered that my dll files ara incompatible with my current wampserver64. I am looking for the correct files.

Comment: You don't mention SQL Server Native Client, did you install it? It'd also be interesting to know whether `phpinfo()` shows the PDO driver for SQLSRV or not.

Comment: @ÂlvaroG.Vicario no I do not see SQLSRV.

Comment: You are using the 64 or 32 version?

Comment: I use 64 bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uninstalled WampServer64 and installed WampServer32. Then everything is OK now.

My connection object

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.$host.';Database=' . $db, $user, $pass, 
                array(
                      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                     )
               );
```

There is another point: I have incidently typed **.mdf** extension after database name which should not be. Because if I write it I get

> 28000 - SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'zkanoca_dbuser'.

error.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable:

```
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
```

in your php.ini.

Comment: there is no such an extension.

Comment: Try with this: `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I have a windows server, where I run PHP, I just checked here are the extensions I have enabled:

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll #(might not need it)
```

And your connection would look like this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mssql:host=1.2.3.4;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not have those files. I have downloaded and copied them to ext folder and then typed their names into php.ini file. I get same error: no driver found

Comment: @zkanoca if driver not found then its not enabled correctly, you might need to download some dll, and place them in `ext` directory, you should use `phpinfo()` to check installation, restart apache and reboot your server